# Space item in column

Tags: flutter

I want to space out the Column on the right side if the image to look the same as the example bur I have tried all 3 of the spaceBetween, spaceEvenly and spaceAround but none seem to work.[image: How I want it to look][image: My try]

This is the code I wrote for the item

```
Widget foodItemCard(BuildContext context, FoodItem prod) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.white),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(prod.imageAddress),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(prod.prodName),
                sauceItemList(context, prod.sauceItems),
                Text('${prod.prodPrice} VND')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget sauceItemList(BuildContext context, List<SauceItem> items) {
  return Column(
    children: List.generate(
        items.length,
        (index) => Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 15,
                  width: 15,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Color(items[index].color)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  items[index].prodName,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(items[index].color)),
                )
              ],
            )),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Row In Food Item Card change its mainAxisAlignment to adjust accordingly. for example to make it center try code below

```
 Widget foodItemCard(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.grey),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10),
        child: Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.amberAccent),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('sampleProd'),
            sauceItemList(context),
            Text('${200} VND')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

--- output be like
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, it just move the children to the right.

Comment: can you give complete code example,

Comment: the code example  you provided is not gonna align as you want with minor modification

Comment: I just have a Listview.builder which return the foodItemCard

Comment: or else add a third child in the row like SizeBox(), then try SpaceEvenly or Space Around in the Row mainAxis Property,

Comment: and also give your Image container either Fraction sizes or Fixed sizes  so you have consistent design over all screen types